# Which sitemap is better?

Tags: sitemap, joomla1.5, xml-sitemap

I have a hand coded sitemap which I know doesn't include every possible scenario of links that are available as I am working with a CMS (Joomla). I have just used an automated generator that created me a sitemap and I am wondering which would be better, the one I created or the automated one. The one I created is very precise but I am always having to update it by hand. I am working with Joomla 1.5 which is pretty outdated and doesn't update the sitemap with links that are created inside the articles. Any thoughts or suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I use a 3rd party application:  http://xml-sitemaps.com

Comment: That is what I have used as well. But I noticed that it would not add everything and that is why I hand coded mine.

Comment: Is there anything in the robots.txt file that is blocking the crawl?

Comment: No, it is getting crawled. I am just wondering which sitemap is better. I have created two. One that is hand created and one that has been automated. I would love to know which of the two are better without having to go line by line through the whole sitemap.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have all URLs and combinations in a sitemap. The crawlers will find the links in the articles themselves on the long term. So working with Joomla sitemap is good enough.